# CSS Two Different Colors (Interior and Exterior) on Single Font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to overlap two font items to create a two tone effect using just HTML/CSS. I can achieve this fairly easily if I want to make the top one color and the bottom another. What I really want to do though is make the outside of the font (icon) one color and the inside another.

Here is the HTML used to create the top/bottom split (includes fontawesome.io):

```
<div>
    <span><i class="icon-li icon-bar-chart"></i></span>
    <i class="icon-li icon-bar-chart"></i>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
div {
    left: 8px;
    position: relative;  
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 60px;
}

div span {
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #6DCAEC;
    overflow: hidden;  
}
```

In a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugA34/)

Here's what I want it to look like:

[Goal](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a36aphzqkrvo0wp/goal.png)

Last note is that I only need the CSS to be compatible with web-kit. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: No, probably not possible to do this.  I recommend just creating a separate image.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple shape so you can create "outline" using ::after

```
.icon-li::after {
    content: ' ';
    border: 5px solid #6DCAEC;
    position: absolute;
    top: .1em;
    left: 0em;
    height: .71em;
    width: .91em;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugA34/2/)

Comment: So I opted to go this route, however I implemented this idea using a span instead of the pseudo ::after element just because it was all inside a hyperlink tag and the ::after broke the link. Great suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try instead of using font with SVG icons .. to use 2 x SVG paths .. or 1 X SVG with multiple paths .. then you can add 1 color for a path and different color for the second path

look here for tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

example:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174"
     xml:space="preserve">

<ellipse fill="#C6C6C6" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/> // first shape 

<path id="bird" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150."/> // second shape 

</svg>
```